# Confusion with exercise 6.43 in Bott Tu

Tags: algebraic-topology, differential-forms, de-rham-cohomology

I am currently working through the book "Differential Forms in Algebraic Topology" by Bott and Tu, though I am confused with one of the problems.

Problem 6.43 on page 75 asks:
"... Find the class u on M such that 
$\Phi^2 = \Phi\wedge\pi^\star u$  in $H^\star_{cv}(E)$"
with $\Phi$ the Thom class of a vector bundle $\pi:E\to M$.

My confusion is with the $\Phi^2$, I am not quite sure what it should mean. The first thing that springs to mind is that it is shorthand for $\Phi\wedge\Phi$, but this would mean $\Phi^2 = 0$, which leaves me wondering why they wouldn't just ask for a form $u$ with $\Phi\wedge\pi^\star 
 u = 0$. Is this what I should be looking for, is there something I am missing about $\Phi\wedge\Phi$, or is $\Phi^2$ something entirely different?

Comment: If $\Phi$ has odd degree, then $\Phi\wedge\Phi = 0$, but this is not necessarily the case if $\Phi$ has even degree.

Comment: Oh, yeah, took me a bit to see this, but it works. Thanks.

Comment: Does my comment constitute a complete answer to your question? If so, I will convert it to an answer. If not, please elaborate on what else would be needed.

Comment: Yeah, was able to do the exercise without any problems thanks to your answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As discussed in the comments, $\Phi^2$ is notation for $\Phi\wedge\Phi$. If $\Phi$ has odd degree, then $\Phi^2 = 0$, but this is not necessarily the case if $\Phi$ has even degree.